# Run python code from jenkins groovy pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way to run python script and code (not as a commandline) directly from a jenking Groovy pipeline?

or from inside a groovy class in a sharedLib

Comment: what wrong with:
sh "python myScript.py"?

I also recommend wrapping it and running inside a docker container.

Comment: i have developers with an arsenal of python scripts and i would like to use them and share memory with them (read runtime vars from groovy or read vars from python) from my groovy piplines, without the need to change each script to return the data i am interested in